# How to get an earlier reversion from a SVN repository?

Tags: svn

If I execute this command

```
svn co https://ltfat.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ltfat ltfat
```

will I get the latest reversion, which is 908.

But I would really like to have reversion 901.

Does someone know how I can do that?

Lots of love,
Louise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the `-r` flag

E.g.

`svn co -r901 https://ltfat.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ltfat ltfat`

Or, you can update your existing checkout to an older revision:

`svn up -r901`

Answer (score 2):

Add `--revision 901` before the url

Answer (score 1):

You can suffix the URL with @revno to get what you want. So something like

```
svn co https://ltfat.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ltfat@901 ltfat
```

should do the trick. The `-r (--revision)` option gives you more fine grained control and can also do things to revision ranges (although I'm not sure about the usefulness of this to the checkout command). You can get more details with

```
svn help checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

svn cat

Please read 
svn help cat
for details.

Comment: This is simply used to output the contents of a file. It can take a -r option to work on an earlier version but it's orthogonal to checking out.